# emacs: Convert python spaces to tabs

Tags: python, emacs, tabs, whitespace

Currently I use following setting in my .emacs file:

```el
;; single tab for every indent
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
    (setq python-indent 4)
    (setq tab-width 4)))
```

This works perfectly for any new file that I create. By if I download a project from git/hg which happened to be on space emacs will not convert them to be on space. How can I force emacs to convert all the spaces to tabs regardless whats the original setting of the file is.

I understand that this would create large chunk of change set if its a git/hg repo but I still like to figure out how to convert any file with space to change it to tabs via my emacs settings.

Answer (score 9):

Mark the entire buffer with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd>, and then use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `tabify`.

Comment: Since this should be idempotent, I guess you could add a function to `python-mode-hook`.  `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'(lambda () (tabify (point-min) (point-max))))`

Comment: Be careful. You *must* set the correct `tab-width` before you `tabify`: tabify converts spaces to tabs based on the current tab-width of the buffer, which is not necessarily the same number of spaces used for indentation by the original author. You will end up with a mixture of tabs and spaces if you get this wrong. (If your python mode is smart enough to automatically figure out the right value for each file and set the tab-width accordingly, then this might not be a problem in practice.)

Comment: ...although I see you are setting tab-width in your python mode hook, so you may well be clobbering any automated value.

Comment: how can I do tabs to spaces?

Comment: @alper That's `M-x untabify`.

Answer (score 3):

Built upon triplee's comment:

```el
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
    (setq python-indent 4)
    (setq tab-width 4))
    (tabify (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Comment: How can I apply this for all programming hooks? @Andreas Röhler

Comment: @alper Try prog-mode-hook, leaving out python-related line.

Comment: If I replace `tabify` with `untabify` will it apply the reverse apporach where tab to 4-space?

Comment: @alper Depends how large the tabs where column-wise, resulting in 4, 8 spaces, whatever.